# Which driver for controlling bipolar stepper motor with a raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, pi-2

I've just purchased this 12v [bipolar stepper motor](https://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/stepper-motor-with-cable.html) and now I'm looking for an appropriate driver to hook it up to the raspberry pi 2. I'm a little overwhelmed by the specs and choices. Which driver should I go for?

I've seen the [ULN2803A](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/darlington-transistors/7141167/) but this seems to be only for unipolar stepper motors. The L293D is described in this [Adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-10-stepper-motors/hardware-l293d), but their motor has five wires and mine has four. Is there a similarly cheap IC I can use for my purpose? Or a more expensive board is fine as long as I can find the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be looking to buy an A4988 based microstepping driver.

You can pick them up on eBay for less than a UK pound (if you are prepared to wait for delivery).

E.g. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/152189401647

Datasheet at http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Motor-Driver-And-Interface-ICs/Bipolar-Stepper-Motor-Drivers/A4988.aspx